# What is the `level` argument in zlib Deflate?

Tags: pdf, zlib

I am trying to parse a PDF in C and I am using the zlib library for deflating. In the documentation, the `zlibInit` function takes an argument which is labeled as `level`. What is the purpose of that argument and how can I obtain it from the PDF stream?

Comment: There is no `zlibInit` in zlib. What library are you using, in what language? Include the language in your tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a `level` argument, then you are using the wrong function to aid in parsing a PDF. `level` is only used for *compression*. For the PDF you need *decompression*. Compression in zlib is called "deflate". Decompression in zlib is called "inflate". You want to inflate, not deflate.

Comment: You just saved me from wasting many more hours of my life. Thank you very much.